# making a perfect square bg around text in css?

Tags: html, css, background

i want to create a perfect square background with a padding of 1px around the text CH.
i have tried this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/q2y0gsds/1/

```css
.credit {
font-size:8px;
font-weight:bold;
letter-spacing:0px;
background:black;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<center>
<div class="credit">CH</div>
</center>
```

Comment: Give `display:inline-block;` to `.credit`. By the way, `<center>` is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set a `width` and `height` to your div

```css
.credit {
font-size:8px;
font-weight:bold;
letter-spacing:0px;
background:black;
color:white;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<center>
<div class="credit">CH</div>
</center>
```